# Difference between main storage and secondary storage and stable storage?

Tags: filesystems, rdbms

I am reading a file systems in RDBMS.

I have a some doubt.

I know some of the differences between these three file system. They are

- Main storage:-

  ```
     * Main storage is temporary.
     * The main storage is directly accessible from CPU.
     * Main storage is a volatile memory.
  ```
- Secondary storage:-

  ```
     * Secondary storage is permanent.
     * Secondary storage is directly accessible form main storage.
     * Secondary storage is a non-volatile memory.
  ```
- Stable storage:-

  ```
     * The stable storage gives the guarantees for the atomicity for a given write operation in database.
     * All logs are written onto the stable storage.
     * In stable storage the data is written in more than one disk.
  ```

Is there any other difference between these three file systems.

Comment: refer to [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_data_storage) to learn more about data storage. Reds

Answer (score 0):

you missed this differences for Stable storage

- recover without data loss from multiple power failures guarantee
- against immediate errors following a write operation, which adds to
  or replaces stored data
- this storage is using more than one disks to hold same data so if write operation is takes places, the same information is written to all connected disks at the same time.

and general differences are,

- Seek time - The average time taken from requesting data to starting
  to read the requested data
- Capacity - The amount of data it is possible to store on a medium
- Write type - Whether it is read only, write only, or readable and
  writable
- Cost - How much it costs per megabyte